# How to refactor complex condition to something better?

Tags: java

I have some range: <101, 998>

I'd like to add that range to the list with this condition:

```
if((i % 10 != 0) && (i != 299 && i != 515 && i != 517 && i != 518) && (i < 303 || i > 309) && (i < 400 || i > 410) && (i < 702 || i > 710) && (i < 800 || i > 810) &&  (i < 900 || i > 910))
```

How to refactor this condition into something better?

My code:

```
   List<Integer> depCodes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 101; i <= 998; i++){
                if((i % 10 != 0) && (i != 299 && i != 515 && i != 517 && i != 518) && (i < 303 || i > 309) && (i < 400 || i > 410) && (i < 702 || i > 710) && (i < 800 || i > 810) &&  (i < 900 || i > 910)){
                    depCodes.add(i);
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
            }
```

Result:

```
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 301, 302, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 511, 512, 513, 514, 516, 519, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 701, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998,
```

Comment: This kind of questions is better asked at [codereview.SE]. because it is about refactoring of running code

Comment: You could use a lookup table, a simple `boolean[999]` array in which you can look up the result. Fill it once in a static initializer using a couple of `for` loops or a helper method.

Comment: Or you could extract the condition into a helper method, which lets you use early returns for all the `false` cases.

Comment: Another approach could be to use a set of ranges that you test the value for, i.e. is it in the range or not? `i = 515` could then be something like `range(515,515).notContains(i)`, `(i < 303 || i > 309)´ would then become `range(303,309).notContains(i)`. To simplify the condition build a list/set of ranges and check each of those (e.g. a `List<Range>`).

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helper method with proper formatting using "inverse" logic:

```
static boolean isGoodCode(int x) {
    return !(
       i < 101 || i > 998 || i % 10 == 0
       || i == 299 
       || (i > 302 && i < 310)
       || (i > 400 && i < 410)
       || i == 515 || i == 517 || i == 518
       || (i > 701 && i < 710)
       || (i > 800 && i < 810)
       || (i > 900 && i < 910)       
    );
}
```

Then the list may be generated using filter:

```
public static List<Integer> getCodes() {
    return IntStream.range(100, 1000)
                    .filter(MyClass::isGoodCode)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// ----
List<Integer> codes = getCodes();
//System.out.println("size = " + codes.size());
//size: 763

codes.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + ", "));
```

Output is the same as in the question.